# Compute rolling average across years while displaying data split by year

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

The [dashboard in the linked workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/rohrkemper#!/vizhome/rollingaverageacrossyears1/Dashboard) shows a table with sales split by year on the top. Below, there's a table with the rolling average of the last 4 weeks, including the current. It's set to show NULL if there are not enough data points. I'd like for it to compute the first January 2018 value based on the current week and 3 full weeks from the end of 2017. Carrying that concept forward, all NULLs from 2018 onward will be eliminated. The NULLs for the first 5 weeks of 2017 will be the only NULL values. The average should always be computed on a full 4 weeks (28 days) even when week 53 doesn't contain 7 days.

How can I write a calculation to achieve what's described above?

I've tried putting the WINDOW_AVG function inside a LOD, but that's not allowed. Furthermore, I've also tried using FIXED and even FIXED inside WINDOW_AVG.

Here's one of my attempts:

```
{FIXED  [Week_int]:
WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Sales]), -4, 0)
}
```

It returns this error: "Error: Level of detail expressions cannot contain table calculations or the ATTR function"

[image: rolling window]

Here's the data structure. It includes one value of Sales per day.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say that week 1 to 4 shouldn't be blank except for first year i.e. 2017?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, Good observation. I wrote that the first 5 weeks of 2017 will be the only NULLs. I agree that intuitively, one might expect only the first 4 weeks. However, week 1 doesn't contain 7 days, so it's excluded from the moving average. This is actually my preferred behavior, to have only full weeks included in the first reported value of 2017. For other years, there should already be a value from week 1 as I described above, based on the previous 4 full weeks or 28 days, even if they span across a year.

Comment: Can you please share your data structure or tell/confirm whether you have date-wise measures?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, yes there are date-wise measures. Your solution looks perfect. I'll upload my revised dashboard now on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I created a dummy data in Excel by creating dates (from 1-1-2017 to 2-2-2021) and filling some random values (unif dist *5000) against these.

I added Week[date] to columns and year[date] to rows as in your screenshot.  I added sum(value) on the text marks card.

Thereafter, I added table calculation --> Moving average --> edited it for previous 4 values , next 0 values, (check current value if you want to include current record), then check Null if there are not enough values. (your requirement).  --> click compute using -**Specific Dimensions** change the order of fields below - *drag Year above than week* (**table across then down will also create the same view**)

You should be able to get a view as desired.

Regarding your query on number of days in the week, Tableau caters it automatically if you have chosen it datepart.

[image]

**Edit** I verified this in Excel, the method is correctly working.

See, the average of first 28 values in Excel

[image]

and the view built in tableau:

[image]

[Here's the corrected dashboard hosted on Tableau Public.](https://public.tableau.com/views/rollingaverageacrossyears/CORRECTdashboard?:language=en&:display_count=y&publish=yes&:origin=viz_share_link)